Add label to hard disk or flash drive that is on disk and will show on all systems it is connected to
Kind of similar to this question, but not quite the same.
I want to know how I can reliably add a persistent label to a disk, especially a USB flash drive or [Micro]SD card, that is on the disk itself, such that when I move the disk to another system, it can be easily identified with the same label - that is, the label is on the disk and enables the disk to 'self-identify' to any system to which it is subsequently connected to.
I am doing this on Windows, and it is apparent that some SD card/USB flash drive manufacturers do not even embed/encode a serial number, let alone a drive label.
I know I can 'rename' a 'volume' in Windows Explorer by right-clicking the drive or selecting it and pressing F2, but this technically isn't a physical disk label, it is a volume label, and the associated volume serial number appears to be assigned by Windows and would be lost if the drive is reformatted.
Anyone know of a reliable way of applying persistent labels to physical hard drives/removable disks that does not involve the use of a configuration file on the host system to map a label upon connecting the disk to the host system?
(Before you joke about printing a sticky label and sticking it to the outside of the physical disk, yes, I can do that, but when I have more than one drive/card plugged into the system I need a way of easily identifying which logical disk in Windows maps to which physical drive).

DOS partition tables don't internally support labels, but FAT32 does (as do GPT partition tables, but I suspect your SD card might use the older format).
If you know the /dev/* path to your device, you can see the partition table by running parted /dev/foo and running the command print and looking at the Partition Table: output. This also shows the partitions present on the device. (Careful with parted, a couple of the commands don't require confirmation and will blow your data away.)
Assuming it has a FAT32 partition, you can use something like fatlabel to relabel that partition to whatever you'd like. Maybe take a look at this answer? How can I change the volume name of a FAT32 filesystem?
If you're looking for a way to identify the device when it's initially plugged in, I'm not sure offhand when paths in /dev/disk/by-label are available, but that might be a path toward something consistent if that's what you're looking for.

I just realized I posted this in the "Linux & Unix" section...D'Oh! Although I did mention I am using Windows. In any case, this answer is about creating volume or partition labels, which is technically not what I want because that is effectively a temporal configuration, but I do see where you are going, and I suspect that the best I can hope for is volume labels. But thanks for the tips. I expect that the serial numbers on HDDs and SSDs are embedded in the drive controller chipset at manufacture. I guess a lot of flash memory makers don't bother with embedded serial numbers.

I'll wait a bit to see if anyone else comes up with any other options. If nothing, then I'll accept your answer.

This short thing might get you on a track forward,
it apparently works on NVME and SSD devices at least (tested here and now),
guessing it being the same for HDD:
It seems USB devices may need special options; see the man page regarding the -device=TYPE option.
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep -i serial
Serial Number:    S5SSNF00BADC0DE

$ smartctl --version | head -n 2
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.8.0-51-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

$ . /etc/os-release | echo $PRETTY_NAME
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS


Edit:
$ lsblk -ape7 -o +SERIAL
will show a serial number for several USB-memory sticks in my collection.
